# Getting Content from GUI into JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a class called "KinectViewer" where I want the content (or the frame) to appear inside of a JScrollPane inside a JSplitPane. However, I can't seem to figure this out despite trying to add the JPanel from KinectViewer into the ScrollPane or trying to bring over the entire class in itself. I also can't seem to find anything like this online.

Here is KinectViewer:

```
package skeleton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

 import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.gui.DWApp;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KinectViewer extends DWApp implements ChangeListener
{

Kinect myKinect;
ViewerPanel3D main_panel;
JSlider elevation_angle;
JCheckBox near_mode;
JCheckBox seated_skeleton;
JCheckBox track_skeleton;
JButton turn_off;
JComboBox depth_resolution;
JComboBox video_resolution;
JCheckBox show_video;
JCheckBox mask_players;
JLabel accelerometer;

public void GUIsetup(JPanel p_root) {


    setLoadingProgress("Intitializing Kinect...",20);
    myKinect=new Kinect();
    if(myKinect.start(true,Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_320x240,Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480)==0)
    {
        DWApp.showErrorDialog("ERROR", "<html><center><br>ERROR: The Kinect device could not be initialized.<br><br>1. Check if the Microsoft's Kinect SDK was succesfully installed on this computer.<br> 2. Check if the Kinect is plugged into a power outlet.<br>3. Check if the Kinect is connected to a USB port of this computer.</center>");
        //System.exit(0); 
    }

    myKinect.computeUV(true);

    near_mode=new JCheckBox("Near mode");
    near_mode.addActionListener(this);

    seated_skeleton=new JCheckBox("Seated skeleton");
    seated_skeleton.addActionListener(this);

    elevation_angle=new JSlider();
    elevation_angle.setMinimum(-27);
    elevation_angle.setMaximum(27);
    elevation_angle.setValue((int)myKinect.getElevationAngle());
    elevation_angle.setToolTipText("Elevation Angle ("+elevation_angle.getValue()+" degrees)");
    elevation_angle.addChangeListener(this);

    turn_off=new JButton("Turn off");
    turn_off.addActionListener(this);

    depth_resolution=new JComboBox();
    depth_resolution.addItem("80x60");
    depth_resolution.addItem("320x240");
    depth_resolution.addItem("640x480");
    depth_resolution.setSelectedIndex(1);
    depth_resolution.addActionListener(this);

    video_resolution=new JComboBox();
    video_resolution.addItem("640x480");
    video_resolution.addItem("1280x960");
    video_resolution.setSelectedIndex(0);
    video_resolution.addActionListener(this);

    track_skeleton=new JCheckBox("Track Skeletons");
    track_skeleton.setSelected(true);
    track_skeleton.addActionListener(this);

    show_video=new JCheckBox("Show video");
    show_video.setSelected(true);
    show_video.addActionListener(this);

    mask_players=new JCheckBox("Mask Players");
    mask_players.setSelected(false);
    mask_players.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel controls=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,6));
    controls.add(new JLabel("Depth Stream:"));
    controls.add(depth_resolution);
    controls.add(near_mode);

    controls.add(new JLabel("Video Stream:"));
    controls.add(video_resolution);
    controls.add(show_video);

    controls.add(new JLabel("Skeleton Stream:"));
    controls.add(track_skeleton);
    controls.add(seated_skeleton);

    controls.add(mask_players);
    accelerometer=new JLabel("0,0,0");
    controls.add(accelerometer);
    controls.add(elevation_angle);
    //controls.add(turn_off);


    setLoadingProgress("Intitializing OpenGL...",60);
    main_panel=new ViewerPanel3D();
    myKinect.setViewer(main_panel);
    myKinect.setLabel(accelerometer);

    p_root.add(main_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p_root.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}

public void GUIclosing()
{
    myKinect.stop();
}

private void resetKinect()
{
    if(turn_off.getText().compareTo("Turn on")==0) return;

    myKinect.stop();
    int depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_INVALID;
    if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==0) depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_80x60;
    else if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==1) depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_320x240;
    else if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==2) depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480;

    int video_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_INVALID;
    if(video_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==0) video_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480;
    else if(video_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==1) video_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_1280x960;


    myKinect.start(track_skeleton.isSelected(),depth_res,video_res);
    myKinect.computeUV(true);
    if(seated_skeleton.isSelected())myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(true);
    if(near_mode.isSelected()) myKinect.setNearMode(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    createMainFrame("Kinect Viewer App");
    app=new KinectViewer();
    setFrameSize(730,570,null);
}

@Override
public void GUIactionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==near_mode)
    {
        if(near_mode.isSelected()) myKinect.setNearMode(true);
        else myKinect.setNearMode(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==seated_skeleton)
    {
        if(seated_skeleton.isSelected()) myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(true);
        else myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==track_skeleton)
    {
        if(track_skeleton.isSelected())
        {
            if(seated_skeleton.isSelected()) myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(true);
            else myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(false);
        }
        else myKinect.stopSkeletonTracking();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==turn_off)
    {
        if(turn_off.getText().compareTo("Turn off")==0)
        {
            myKinect.stop();
            turn_off.setText("Turn on");
        }
        else
        {
            turn_off.setText("Turn off");
            resetKinect();
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==depth_resolution)
    {
        resetKinect();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==video_resolution)
    {
        resetKinect();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==show_video)
    {
        main_panel.setShowVideo(show_video.isSelected());
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==mask_players)
    {
        myKinect.maskPlayers(mask_players.isSelected());
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==elevation_angle)
    {
        if(!elevation_angle.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            myKinect.setElevationAngle(elevation_angle.getValue());
            elevation_angle.setToolTipText("Elevation Angle ("+elevation_angle.getValue()+" degrees)");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the splitpane class (TestSplitPanels.java):

```
package skeleton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.accessibility.AccessibleContext;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

public class TestSplitPanels extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    final TestSplitPanels tps = new TestSplitPanels();
    frame.setContentPane(tps);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public TestSplitPanels() {

    JTable jt3 = new JTable();

    JButton loginbutton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton database = new JButton("Database");
    // JButton LiveFeed = new JButton("Live Feed");

    final JPanel jsr1 = new JPanel();
    final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.addTab("Floor 1", new Floor1Panel());
    jtp.addTab("Floor 2", new Floor2Panel());
    jtp.addTab("Floor 3", new Floor3Panel());
    add(jtp);
    final JScrollPane jsr3 = new JScrollPane();

    jsr3.setViewportView(jt3);
    ActionListener ButtonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    ActionListener DatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();

    jsr1.add(loginbutton);
    jsr1.add(database);
    loginbutton.addActionListener(ButtonHandler);
    database.addActionListener(DatabaseHandler);
    jsr1.setVisible(true);

    // JPanel feed = new KinectViewer().app;
    // jsr3.add(feed);  

    JSplitPane jsl1 = new JSplitPane();
    JSplitPane jsl2 = new JSplitPane();

    jsl1.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    jsl1.setTopComponent(jsr1);
    jsl1.setBottomComponent(jsl2);
    jsl1.setResizeWeight(0.33); // <-- here

    jsl2.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    jsl2.setTopComponent(jtp);
    jsl2.setBottomComponent(jsr3);
    jsl2.setResizeWeight(0.5); // <-- here

    this.addAncestorListener(new BaseAncestorListener() {
        @Override
        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
            System.out.println("jsr1 size: " + jsr1.getSize());
            System.out.println("jsr2 size: " + jtp.getSize());
            System.out.println("jsr3 size: " + jsr3.getSize());
            System.out.println("----");
        }
    });

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(jsl1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static class BaseAncestorListener implements AncestorListener {

    @Override
    public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

public void init() {
    try {
      SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      System.out.println("Can't create because of " + exc);
    }
  }
}
}
```

How can I get the same GUI functions to show up in the SplitPanes from KinectViewer?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this `DWApp` class that your KinectView extends from? What is its inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure. I got this from [this site](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/index.php). During setting everything up, I imported a project from git, and used a uri of "http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/j4kdemo" as seen [here](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/examples.php#how).

Comment: Then it is up to you to study the source code and find out how to use it.

Comment: Ok. Should that greatly effect whether or not I can use the GUI in my other class?

Comment: Understanding the code you're using will impact on everything.

Comment: You can't put a frame inside another container

Comment: Ok, so looking at the source code, the DWApp class is a class in the edu.ufl.digitalworlds.gui package in the ufdw.jar (downloaded via site posted above). It has two types of its class: one for a java application (which I'm using) and one for an applet. Inside the class are a bunch of methods seeming to deal with application look and processes (word sizing, formating, error dialogs, ect.). Does this help at all?